# User Authentication in Java using 128-bit AES encryption in CBC mode with PKCS #5 padding

Tags: java, security, encryption

I am using 128-bit AES encryption in CBC mode with PKCS #5 padding to save passwords to my database.
However, when I try to log in, the system tells me the password is invalid even though I use the correct password.

On my UserSetup class, these are my codes for encrypting the passwords and saving them to my database:

```
try {
    String input = simple_text.getText();

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(keyString.getBytes());
    byte[] key = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, key, 0, key.length);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

    // encrypt
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println("encrypted: " + new String(encrypted));
    encrypt_text .setText(new String(encrypted));
} catch (Exception e2) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2);
}

try {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO user(username,password) VALUES(?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=VALUES(username),password=VALUES(password)";

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    pst.setString(1, fLoginName.getText());
    pst.setString(2, encrypt_text.getText());

    pst.execute();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "saved");
} catch (Exception e2) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2);
}
```

On my Login Class, I have the following codes:

```
 String sql ="select * from user where username=? and password=?";
 if(loginNameField.getText().equals("me") && passwordField.getText().equals("me")){
    frmLoginWindow.dispose();
    new GridMain().setVisible(true);                            
 }else{
    try{
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,loginNameField.getText());
        pst.setString(2,passwordField.getText());

        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password is correct ");
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
            //  close();
            frmLoginWindow.dispose();
            new GridMain().setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password is not correct");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    } finally {
        try{
          rs.close();
          pst.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

My encrypted passwords are saving successfully, but I need a way to match my login password with the encrypted passowrd, since AES encryption does not give the same encrypted value even if you encrypt the same password.

Answer (score 2):

AES is an encryption algorithm. You try to use it as a password hash algorithm. The problem is that encrypting the same thing several times will not yield the same result every time. The initialization vector (IV) introduces randomness into the process so that you will not get the same result twice.

You would need to decrypt the password to check it or switch to a password hashing algorithm such as PBKDF2. Keep in mind that AES produces binary data (`byte[]`) which you cannot simply convert to `String`. You need to encode it with something like Base64. This may also be necessary for the output of hashing functions.

Comment: You are right. My problem is 'how do I decrypt it?' Any help on coding?

Comment: @myelow The same as encryption with the difference that you use `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE` instead of `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE` and pass the encrypted password instead of the plaintext password.

Comment: Thanks I did, but it gave me this error message: "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException:input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cypher"

Comment: @myelow That's probably because you're converting the ciphertext from `byte[]` to `String` and that way you lose some characters. You need to encode the ciphertext to Base64 before saving it in the DB and when you retrieve it, convert it back from Base64 to binary.